Error de validación de POST desde el servidor local
Estoy probando realizar un POST con un código en FLUTTER a un servidor local en el puerto 3000. La función que utilizo es:
 Future<void> realizarPost() async {
  final url = Uri.parse('http://localhost:3000/post');
  final datos = {
    "titulo": "Mario",
    "body": "El propio llamando desde Flutter",
  };
  final respuesta = await http.post(url, body: (datos));

  if (respuesta.statusCode == 200) {
    print('Solicitud POST exitosa');
  } else {
    print('Error al realizar el POST: ${respuesta.statusCode}');
  }
}

Pero recibo desde el terminal el error:

[nodemon] 3.1.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter rs
[nodemon] watching path(s): .
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting node app.js
Una API de Node JS se escucha en el puerto: 3000
la base de datos está conectada
CREATING POST:  { _id: new ObjectId('667ed51765c758a8344323a1') }
Error al insertar el documento: Error: Post validation failed: body: Path body is required., title: Path title is required.
at ValidationError.inspect (E:\node-js\api_server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:50:26)
at formatValue (node:internal/util/inspect:805:19)
at inspect (node:internal/util/inspect:364:10)
at formatWithOptionsInternal (node:internal/util/inspect:2298:40)
at formatWithOptions (node:internal/util/inspect:2160:10)
at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:351:14)
at console.warn (node:internal/console/constructor:384:61)
at E:\node-js\api_server\controllers\posts.js:53:13
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
errors: {
body: ValidatorError: Path body is required.
at validate (E:\node-js\api_server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1385:13)
at SchemaType.doValidate (E:\node-js\api_server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1369:7)
at E:\node-js\api_server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3060:18
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
properties: [Object],
kind: 'required',
path: 'body',
value: undefined,
reason: undefined,
[Symbol(mongoose#validatorError)]: true
},
title: ValidatorError: Path title is required.
at validate (E:\node-js\api_server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1385:13)
at SchemaType.doValidate (E:\node-js\api_server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1369:7)
at E:\node-js\api_server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3060:18
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
properties: [Object],
kind: 'required',
path: 'title',
value: undefined,
reason: undefined,
[Symbol(mongoose#validatorError)]: true
}
},
_message: 'Post validation failed'
}

He probado varios esquemas y siempre recibo este error. ¿Alguien ha recibido este error y como se puede solucionar?

Esto depende de como tengas configurado la api a consultar, lo primero que veo es que hay una clave "title" y tu lo tienes definido en flutter como "titulo", esto a tomar en cuenta:
 final datos = {
    "titulo": "Mario", //reemplazar titulo por title
    "body": "El propio llamando desde Flutter",
  };

Sin embargo, asegurate de estar configurando de manera adecuada el proyecto donde recibes los datos que envias. Porque el error lo que te dice es que los datos que espera recibir la api no están llegando(title y body).

Si, tienes razón. Pero en otras pruebas que he realizado me he asegurado que las claves usadas en el llamado a Post coincidan exactamente con el esquema del modelo de mongoose y me aparece el mismo error.

En relación a la pregunta anterior y a una de las respuestas que ha recibido, muestro el código corregido con la sugerencia hecha:
Future<void> realizarPost() async {
    final url = Uri.parse('http://localhost:3000/post');
    final datos = {
      "title": "Mario",
      "body": "El propio llamando desde Flutter",
    };
    final respuesta = await http.post(url, body: (datos));

    if (respuesta.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Solicitud POST exitosa');
    } else {
      print('Error al realizar el POST: ${respuesta.statusCode}');
    }
  }
´´´
También comparto el modelo de esquema que se ejecuta en el servidor:
´´´
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: 'title is required',
        minlength: 4,
        maxlength: 150
    },

    body: {
        type: String,
        required: 'body is required',
        minlength: 4,
        maxlength: 2000

    }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema); 

Por último, quiero agregar la respuesta recibida del mismo servidor cuando ejecuto un POST desde la aplicación POSTMAN:

RS
[nodemon] starting node app.js
Una API de Node JS se escucha en el puerto: 3000
la base de datos está conectada
CREATING POST:  {
title: 'Mario',
body: 'ejecutado desde POSTMAN',
_id: new ObjectId('667ef2f7f071cea1490b6162')
}
Documento insertado exitosamente!
Es decir, mi servidor funciona bien y en particular la ejecución del POST desde FLUTTER que estoy realizando, cumple con todas las condiciones para que se complete exitosamente, estas las puedo enumerar:


Se realiza la conexión al puerto 3000.
El formato de los datos cumple con el esquema del modelo establecido en el servidor.
El llamado a la función de creación del POST en el servidor se realiza correctamente, un indicativo de ello es la respuesta inicial del servidor "CREATING POST:  { _id: new ObjectId('667ef10d98a40f5c89425f25') }", ya que este es un mensaje programado en el código:

exports.createPost = (req, res) => {
    const post = new Post(req.body);
    console.log("CREATING POST: ", post);


He consultado este tema con Gemini y la solución que me ha dado es convertir la variable datos a formato json con el método jsonEncode(datos), pero haciendo ésto recibo la misma respuesta del servidor.
En resumen, los datos tienen el formato del esquema del modelo y la conversión a formato json no corrige el error.
Por otro lado, después de una amplia consulta en la internet todas las implementaciones de POST con FLUTTER son iguales o parecidas a las que estoy comentando en esta publicación.
¿Nuevamente pregunto, alguien tiene idea de lo que ocurre en este caso y la forma de solucionarlo?


Hola Mario, bienvenido, esta no es una respuesta, sino una ampliación de la pregunta, te sugiero que la elimines, edites tu pregunta y agregues en ella, todo lo que creas necesario, así evitarás recibir votos negativos.

No sé si esto debiera ser una edición a la pregunta (si el problema sigue siendo el mismo que al inicio pero la información aclara el contexto o amplía la información) o una nueva pregunta (si ya se resolvió el problema original y ahora hay un nuevo problema). Pero lo que no es es una respuesta a la pregunta original. Por favor haz de nuevo el [tour] para aprender como funciona StackOverflow.

nadie te va a responder una respuesta ;)
